# Is it possible to make a bone rotate on its tail like it would on its head?

Tags: bones

So if the middle bone has IK, can the top bone be made to rotate on its tail, instead of moving with the entire Armature, almost as if it was pinned in place? Any help is appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bones always rotate on their head, but you can duplicate the bone in edit mode (Shift D, Esc), then right click and choose "switch direction", then make the new bone parent of the old one (keep offset), so that rotating it will perform the desired motion.

[image]

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to work in Pose Mode, only Edit Mode. Is there a way to make it work in Pose Mode?

Comment: In edit mode it cannot work because in edit mode the IK constraint doesn't act. Make sure the IK constraint is pointing to the (head of  the) child bone. In pose mode it works (if I understood what you're looking for). Check also if your pivot point preference is the default "median point". If the rig is correct, in pose mode rotating the parent will result in the child rotating around the desired pivot point (head of the parent) and the IK chain follows the child's head. What is not working?

Comment: I did what your answer said, but when I move the middle bone up, the image on the right side is what I get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4ddAOVlANARWNUjN21pndT7JOIBy90N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If the bones are supposed to be rigid (no stretching), the movement has to be performed by rotating the parent, not by moving the middle bone.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I really don't think I'm entirely understanding your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by applying an IK constraint to the top bone and then targeting it towards an empty at the same coordinates as the top bone's tail. It also seems to help if you remove the IK from the middle bone and just have it on the top bone. I hope this helps anyone who's having a similar issue.